# How to access a model through List in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to sort the `ValidatingCarrier` in ascending order so I thought of getting it into a List and sorting it using Orderby in my controller.

I have the following Model Classes:

```
public class sort
    {
        public OTAAirLowFareSearchRS OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS { get; set; }
    }
public class OTAAirLowFareSearchRS
    {
        public int PricedItinCount { get; set; }
        public int BrandedOneWayItinCount { get; set; }
        public int SimpleOneWayItinCount { get; set; }
        public int DepartedItinCount { get; set; }
        public int SoldOutItinCount { get; set; }
        public int AvailableItinCount { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public Success success { get; set; }
        public Warnings Warnings { get; set; }
        public PricedItineraries PricedItineraries { get; set; }
        public TPAExtensions8 TPA_Extensions { get; set; }
    }

public class PricedItinerary
    {
        public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
        public AirItinerary AirItinerary { get; set; }
        public List<AirItineraryPricingInfo> AirItineraryPricingInfo { get; set; }
        public TicketingInfo TicketingInfo { get; set; }
        public TPAExtensions7 TPA_Extensions { get; set; }
    }

public class AirItineraryPricingInfo
    {
        public string PricingSource { get; set; }
        public string PricingSubSource { get; set; }
        public ItinTotalFare ItinTotalFare { get; set; }
        public PTCFareBreakdowns PTC_FareBreakdowns { get; set; }
        public FareInfos2 FareInfos { get; set; }
        public TPAExtensions6 TPA_Extensions { get; set; }
        public string LastTicketDate { get; set; }
    }
public class TPAExtensions6
    {
        public DivideInParty DivideInParty { get; set; }
        public ValidatingCarrier ValidatingCarrier { get; set; }
    }
```

The following is the way I am trying to access it in my controller. I cannot access beyond `PriceItinerary` cause the reset goes as a List.

```
 sort searchResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sort>(tar.ToString());
 var sortingname = searchResponse.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary;
 List<PricedItinerary> lstname = new List<PricedItinerary>();
```

Any kind of help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You have create the object first

```
searchResponse.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary obj = new searchResponse.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary;
```

var x = obj.SequenceNumber;

Comment: sort searchResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sort>(tar.ToString()); 
I have an object already called search response and its a local Variable.. Object cannot be created as you say.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `LINQ SelectMany` makes a projection os `IEnumerable` into one `IEnumerable`.
With the given model and assuming that you need to get a list of `ValidatingCarrier` starting on `PricedItinerary` , let's go do it!

```
    IEnumerable<ValidatingCarrier> IEValidatingCarrier = searchResponse.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary
        .SelectMany(p => p.AirItineraryPricingInfo.SelectMany(a => a.TPA_Extensions.ValidatingCarrier)); //This would give you an IEnumerable<ValidatingCarrier>
    IEnumerable<ValidatingCarrier> LstValidatingCarrier = IEValidatingCarrier.OrderBy(o => o.OrderBySomething).ToList(); //And finally, your ordered list!
```

You can also do it all at once, something like this:

```
searchResponse.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary
    .SelectMany(p => p.AirItineraryPricingInfo.SelectMany(a => a.TPA_Extensions.ValidatingCarrier))
    .OrderBy(o => o.OrderBySomething).ToList();
```

Hope it helps! Plase if I don't understand well your question, please let me know!

Comment: I cannot access AirItineraryPricingInfo cause it is a list inside PricedItinerary... This is the main problem could you please help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access "AirItineraryPricingInfo" with the instance of "PricedItinerary"? If it is so, then this helps, otherwise please ignore.

```
public class PricedItinerary : AirItineraryPricingInfo
{
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
    public AirItinerary AirItinerary { get; set; }
    public List<AirItineraryPricingInfo> AirItineraryPricingInfo { get; set; }
    public TicketingInfo TicketingInfo { get; set; }
    public TPAExtensions7 TPA_Extensions { get; set; }
}
```

In controller if we create instance for "PricedItinerary", we can access inherited class.